# How to add Combobox to datagridview headers?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I would like to add Combobox at position of headers: Electrical, Water, Traffic, Entertainment, Shopping.

How to identify the location of these headers?

[image]

Any tips on these will be great help. Thanks in advance.

My code is below:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add columns
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colDateStart1", "Start");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colDateEnd1", "End");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colDateStart2", "Start");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colDateEnd2", "End");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colDateStart3", "Start");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colDateEnd3", "End");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colDateStart4", "Start");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colDateEnd4", "End");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colDateStart5", "Start");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colDateEnd5", "End");

        // Add rows
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(3);
        this.dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

        for (int j = 0; j < this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[j].Width = 45;
        }

        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight * 2;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        this.dataGridView1.CellPainting += new DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellPainting);
        this.dataGridView1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(dataGridView1_Paint);
        this.dataGridView1.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(dataGridView1_Scroll);
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnWidthChanged += new DataGridViewColumnEventHandler(dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged);

        // Add combobox for header
        AddCbbHeaders();

        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }

    private void AddCbbHeaders()
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        cb.MaxDropDownItems = 2;
        cb.Items.Add(new string[] { "", "Electrical", "Water ", "Traffic", "Entertaiment", "Shopping" });
        cb.Value = "";
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] = cb;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rtHeader = this.dataGridView1.DisplayRectangle;
        rtHeader.Height = this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight / 2;
        this.dataGridView1.Invalidate(rtHeader);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rtHeader = this.dataGridView1.DisplayRectangle;
        rtHeader.Height = this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight / 2;
        this.dataGridView1.Invalidate(rtHeader);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arrTasktype = { "Electrical", "Water ", "Traffic", "Entertaiment", "Shopping" };
        for (int j = 0; j < 10;)
        {
            Rectangle r1 = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(j, -1, true);
            int w2 = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(j + 1, -1, true).Width;

            r1.X += 1;
            r1.Y += 1;
            r1.Width = r1.Width + w2 - 2;
            r1.Height = r1.Height / 2 - 2;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor), r1);

            StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(arrTasktype[j / 2],
                                  this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font,
                                  new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor),
                                  r1,
                                  format);
            j += 2;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
        {
            Rectangle r2 = e.CellBounds;
            r2.Y += e.CellBounds.Height / 2;
            r2.Height = e.CellBounds.Height / 2;
            e.PaintBackground(r2, true);
            e.PaintContent(r2);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: just to undestand a little bit more... you want a combobox to change between Electrical, water, traffic...etc??

Comment: To clarify, are you already merging the column headers as shown in your screenshot and you want to add a `ComboBox` as well?

Comment: Hi NicoRiff, OhBeWise. 
Yes, exactly. I want a combobox to change between Electrical, water, traffic...Values of combobox: Electrical, water, traffic... Any tips on these will be great help. Thanks!

Comment: I am guessing that putting a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` into merged cells is not going to be easy since the `DataGridView` does not really have cell merging features, hence your need for the `CellPainting` event. Have you considered simply separating the header from the `DataGridView`? Example, place a regular `ComboBox` with the same width as the two “start” “end” columns just above those two columns. I a guessing this would be much easier to implement. Just a thought.

Comment: Hi JohnG. Example, place a regular ComboBox with the same width as the two “start” “end” columns just above those two columns => if doing so, necessary to merge the two cells in the DataGridView or puts ComboBox outside the DataGridView ?

Comment: You can nest the combobox and the need to adapt size and poistion in a few DGV events wrt to resize, move etc..

Comment: I think that maybe it is difficult for what I want to do with the current code. Is there any other way !?

Comment: @MinhKiyo Yes I am suggesting you pull the combo boxes out of the datagridview. If you do this, you take merging cells completely out of the picture.